# SSIS mySQL ADO.NET connection string

Tags: sql-server, mysql, ssis, ado.net

I want to make my SSIS project can be configure through project parameters. So I use project parameters to store connection strings. But the connection string which I copied from the mysql connection manager not working. After I assign the parameter value which I copied from the connection manager it self, to connection manager by expression, It says:

> An error has occurred while connecting MySQL Server: Could not create a managed connection manager

How to fix this? I think this is a problem about connection string.

Comment: Can you post the connection string that is being derived?

Comment: Start by hard-coding the connection string. If it works hard-coded, then the problem isn't the connection string, but something with how you're managing the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things that can causes this issue:

1. You are running under 64Bit mode

*in the project properties window, go to Debugging tab, and set Run64BitRuntime as false. and try again.*

2. If SSIS Server and DEV Computer have different Connector/.Net Versions

*This will occur after deployment*

3. You are missing the provider in the connectionstring

*You have to add `;Provider=MySQLProv` or `;Provider=MSDASQL` or other provider name (if you are not using these providers) to the connection string*

**References**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120800/ssis-error-could-not-create-a-managed-connection-manager-vs-2010-adonet
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/392c89cb-19d1-48c8-8d54-e8ae0e75f8e8/could-not-create-a-managed-connection-manager-ssis-package-from-ssms-windows-7-64-bit?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/